# defining and instantiate class at once

Tags: c++

i just found out we can defining and instantiate class at once like this

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class PLAYERS
{
public:
    int value3;
    PLAYERS(int value3)
    {
        this->value3 = value3;
    }
}play1(2), play2(3), play3(7);

int main()
{
    play1.value3 = 2;
    PLAYERS play4();
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl << play1.value3;
    return 0;
}
```

what is it called?
when i delete the argument on instantiation of play1, play2, play3 like play4. it will compile error but the play4 is fine. how it can be?

Comment: `PLAYERS play4();` is a function declaration anyway

Comment: Maybe split this into two questions? The `play4()` one is a duplicate.

Comment: @StoryTeller ah yes, stupid me, i intend to call default constructor but i'm forgot to call default constructor must be not use parenthesis or it will be function declaration and i laugh at myself because there is no default constructor in that class haha.. after i fix the code it compiles fine, just my mistake. thank you

Comment: @juanchopanza yes i will edit it, maybe i will delete the second question. if i may can you post the link of that same question?

Comment: downvoted. please dont modify the whole question,after solving it, just because you are lazy to create a new thread. this will be confusing to the future researcher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just called multiple declarations, no special name as far as I'm aware.

You're just making use of a shortened way of doing so, by having the declarations between the closing brace of the class definition and the semi-colon, which is perfectly valid but unusual.